# How to remove the emphasis characters on row names when using pandoc in R

Tags: r, pandoc

I am using `pandoc.table()` to print out the data frame object, with certain cells highlighted by specifying the parameter, `emphasize.strong.cells`. But, the same emphasis characters on row names add some visual complexity. How can I remove these emphasis character on row names.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no option to disable highlighting row names in `pander` ATM. Please file a [new issue on GH](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander) for this feature if you wish, or you might simply transform the row names into a normal variable as a workaround until then.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for [opening an issue for this feature request](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues/115) on GitHub, it should work now:

```
> panderOptions('table.split.table', Inf)
> pander(head(mtcars), emphasize.rownames = FALSE)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      &nbsp;         mpg   cyl   disp   hp   drat   wt    qsec   vs   am   gear   carb 
------------------- ----- ----- ------ ---- ------ ----- ------ ---- ---- ------ ------
     Mazda RX4       21     6    160   110   3.9   2.62  16.46   0    1     4      4   

   Mazda RX4 Wag     21     6    160   110   3.9   2.875 17.02   0    1     4      4   

    Datsun 710      22.8    4    108    93   3.85  2.32  18.61   1    1     4      1   

  Hornet 4 Drive    21.4    6    258   110   3.08  3.215 19.44   1    0     3      1   

 Hornet Sportabout  18.7    8    360   175   3.15  3.44  17.02   0    0     3      2   

      Valiant       18.1    6    225   105   2.76  3.46  20.22   1    0     3      1   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

> panderOptions('table.emphasize.rownames', FALSE)
> pander(head(mtcars))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      &nbsp;         mpg   cyl   disp   hp   drat   wt    qsec   vs   am   gear   carb 
------------------- ----- ----- ------ ---- ------ ----- ------ ---- ---- ------ ------
     Mazda RX4       21     6    160   110   3.9   2.62  16.46   0    1     4      4   

   Mazda RX4 Wag     21     6    160   110   3.9   2.875 17.02   0    1     4      4   

    Datsun 710      22.8    4    108    93   3.85  2.32  18.61   1    1     4      1   

  Hornet 4 Drive    21.4    6    258   110   3.08  3.215 19.44   1    0     3      1   

 Hornet Sportabout  18.7    8    360   175   3.15  3.44  17.02   0    0     3      2   

      Valiant       18.1    6    225   105   2.76  3.46  20.22   1    0     3      1   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix for printing data frames with pander.

```
no.emphasis.table <- function(df){
  the.row.names <- rownames(df)
  add.space <- function(x){
    return(paste0(x, '&nbsp;'))
  }
  the.row.names.m <- as.vector(sapply(the.row.names, add.space))
  rownames(df) <- NULL
  df <- cbind(the.row.names.m, df)
  colnames(df)[1] <- ''
  v.justify <- vector()
  v.justify[seq(1, length(df))] <- 'center'
  v.justify[1] <- 'left'
  set.alignment(v.justify) # Need to explicitly set alignment for first column
  return(df)
}
```

Wrap data frames with this function before printing, e.g.:

```
pander(no.emphasis.table(df))
```